# iOS contraints without explicit frame dimensions

Tags: ios, autolayout, constraints

Whenever I fiddle with iOS autolayout, I run into the same issue (which I solve mostly by fiddling with it until it works, then carefully backing away and trying not to touch anything ever again).

Namely, the issue is that what I'd *like* to do is pretty much lay out everything in relationship to its parent, i.e., (or at least I've always assumed) using constraints to place something against the right edge, *n* pixels in from the left edge, etc.

But I invariably run into issues both warning-wise (with a console full of conflicts) and behavior-wise (with misbehaving layout) at runtime. The reason seems to be that it's impossible not to give frame rectangle x, y, width, and height for any given view. So if anything changes in the layout, my constraints are no longer going to be in sync with those explicit coordinates that there's no way to avoid providing.

Is there a way to use an "auto" value for any/all coordinate of the frame rectangle as opposed to an explicit value, the way that, say, every other layout system ever invented does?

I'm certain I'm missing something obvious, but I've been over and over all the Apple and third-party documentation I can find without enlightenment.

Comment: For autolayout to work, it must be able to determine a position and size for each item.  Some items, such as a `UILabel` have an intrinsic size (determined by the label's content) so it may be sufficient just to constrain its position.  Other objects, like a tableview, don't have an intrinsic size and you will need to provide constraints that either provide the size or allow it to be inferred (for example, by specifying top & bottom spacing from other objects).  Having too many constraints can be just as much of an issue as too few - you can end up with conflicts.

Comment: You need to think about your layout - what needs to be fixed size, what is going to change size on different devices - create constraints accordingly

Comment: Thank you for your response. But my issue is that one *has* to specify the size of an item: for instance, a webview has a frame rectangle that must be specified with CGFloat coordinates for x, y, width, and height. I'm finding I'm having to manually adjust that frame size (sometimes) when the layout changes, which seems contrary to the whole idea of autolayout and constraints.

Comment: This doesn't seem right. Have you got a code or maybe storyboard screenshot you can share?

Comment: I agree with Tom - You don't have to specify those things, but a web view doesn't have an intrinsic content size, so autolayout must be able to infer its size.  For example, If you had, from top to bottom, a label, a web view and a button and constrained the top of the label to the top of the view, the bottom of the button to the top of the web view, the bottom of the web view to the top of the button and the bottom of the button to the bottom of the view, it would be OK; the label and the button have intrinsic heights, so autolayout can infer the web view height.

Comment: If it was a tableview at the bottom you have a problem, because now there are two items without implicit heights, so the overall layout is ambiguous.  You need to tell autolayout the desired height of at least one of those two things.